# Adding polynomials represented as maps

Tags: functional-programming, scala, comparative-review, hash-map

I'm using maps to represent a polynomial.
The key is the exponent and the value is the coefficient : `Map(exp -> coef)`

e.g. `2.5*x^5 + 3.0` is represented by : `Map(5 -> 2.5, 0 -> 3.0)`

I wrote 3 functions (in *Scala*) to add such polynomials. Which one is the most elegant ? Do you have another version that is preferable/better ? (Implementations in another language such as Haskell are welcome)

Here is a sample testcase :

```
val polynom1 = Map(0 -> 1.0, 1 -> 2.0, 2 -> 1.0)
val polynom2 = Map(0 -> 1.0, 1 -> (-2.0), 2 -> 1.0)
val expectedSum = Map(0 -> 2.0, 1 -> 0.0, 2 -> 2.0)
```

Here are the implementations :

```
def addMap1(lhs: Map[Int, Double], rhs: Map[Int, Double]) =
  ((lhs.keys ++ rhs.keys) map { k =>
    (k, lhs.getOrElse(k, 0.0) + rhs.getOrElse(k, 0.0))
  }).toMap



def addMap2(lhs: Map[Int, Double], rhs: Map[Int, Double]) = {
    def adjust(kv: (Int, Double)) = {
      val (exp, coef) = kv
      (exp, coef + lhs.getOrElse(exp, 0.0))
    }
    lhs ++ (rhs map adjust)
  }



def addMap3(lhs: Map[Int, Double], rhs: Map[Int, Double]) = {
    def addTerms(acc: Map[Int, Double], x: (Int, Double)) = {
      val (exp, coef) = x
      acc + (exp -> (coef + rhs.getOrElse(exp, 0.0)))
    }
    (lhs foldLeft rhs)(addTerms)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the second implementation of the function is the most readable and concise. There is just the name of `def adjust` that should be changed. `adjust` is too vague, `sumCoeffs` would be more concrete.

It's probably a matter of taste, but the first implementation seems to contain too much nesting (parenthesis and braces). The third implementation looks also a bit more complex than the second, mostly due to the mechanism of `foldLeft`.

By the way, I've got two suggestions that may slightly improve this code.

1. Omitting dots for function calls and parenthesis for arguments are *not* among the recommendations of the [official Scala style guide](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html) (sections Arity-0 and Arity-1). This practice can reduce the readability. For example, I find that `rhs.map(adjust)` and `lhs.foldLeft(rhs)(addTerms)` are easier to perceive for a human-shaped reader than the respective expressions in the original code.
2. There are several occurrences of `getOrElse(exp, 0.0)` that can be extracted in a small helper function like `private def coefFor(exp : Int, polynoms : Map[Int, Double]) = polynoms.getOrElse(exp, 0.0)`. This will allow to transform the respective instructions into more elegant, for example: `(exp, coef + coefFor(exp, lhs))`. But since among the three functions only one will be chosen/used, this will eliminate the duplications and the relevance of this remark.

Comment: Another alternative to repeated use of `getOrElse` would be to create the map with a chained call to `.withDefaultValue`

Answer (score 1):

A more functional way would be to use a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) type class.

A monoid in short has two operations :

- empty / zero / identity
- append

A simple example is a monoid for integer addition: `0` as the empty/neutral element and `+` as the append operation.

There are a few libraries in Scala (like Scalaz, Cats/Spire) which define `Monoid` and contain monoid instances for types such as `Int`, `Map`, ...

The only problem in your case is that a lawfull monoid for `Double` cannot be defined (because of its hardware representation).

- Since you were already planning to use `Double`, you could use an unlawful monoid instance for `Double`.

  Using scalaz and [scalaz-outlaws](https://github.com/typelevel/scalaz-outlaws) as an example, this then could look like :

  ```
  import scalaz.syntax.monoid._        // use |+| syntax
  import scalaz.std.map._              // get monoid instance for Map
  import scalaz.std.anyVal._           // get monoid instance for Int
  import scalaz.outlaws.std.double._   // get monoid instance for Double 

  polynom1 |+| polynom2
  ```
- You could also give [Spire](https://github.com/non/spire) a closer look, which includes [`Real`](https://github.com/non/spire/blob/master/GUIDE.md#real) (which can store real numbers in any desired precision and has a lawful monoid) and [`Polynomial`](https://github.com/non/spire/blob/master/GUIDE.md#polynomialc).

Comment: Thank you for you answer (+1) ! I wasn't aware that such type class existed. Is there no "ring" or "group" type class ? I suppose that it would be even better...

Comment: You should give Spire a closer look, it has type classes for [`Ring`](https://github.com/non/spire/blob/master/GUIDE.md#rings-and-fields) and also for `Semigroup` (which has the `|+|` append operation but no empty element).